# 条件を満たす65%キーボードは存在しますか?

Tags: ハードウェア

コーディング用のキーボードはありますか
下記条件のキーボードで，なおかつコスパの高いキーボードを探してます．

が，なかなか条件にあったキーボードが見つからずにさまよっています．
海外の怪しすぎない通販サイトでもokです．
条件を満たす選択肢を提示していただけたら非常にありがたいです．

よろしくお願いいたします．

### 必須条件

- soft使わずkeyboardだけでcaps lockをctrlにできる
- 英語配列

  - 他のkeyboard触っても使えるぐらいのノーマルさは欲しい
- 65% keyboard

  - 矢印があったほうが安心?

### あったらいいなと思う条件

- wireless接続

  - 最悪技適なくて日本で使えなくても可
  - 今まで無線使ったことないが有線のほうが良い?
- メカニカル  cherry MX silver軸を検討

  - 赤，黒でも可
- hotswap
- デザインがかっこいい

#### 今まで使ってたキーボード

- 75% keyboard
- cherry MX Black
- 有線

Comment: 「なかなか条件にあったキーボードが見つからず」
とありますが、どのようなキーボードを検討して、なぜ条件に合わなかったのかを示したほうが良いです。

Comment: 「おすすめはなんですか？」のようなアンケート形式の質問は、回答が発散してしまうので、[コミュニティの判断でクローズされる場合があります。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) (特に "デザインがかっこいい" 等)

Comment: 「soft使わずkeyboardだけでcaps lockをctrlにできる」というのは、ディップスイッチなどのハードウェアスイッチでcaps lockをcaptsかctrlか切り替えられなければならないという意味であっていますか？

Comment: 「おすすめはなんですか？」と聞いた場合、「主観性が高い」としてクローズされる可能性があります。そのような質問にならないように「存在するかどうか」に質問を変更しました。それでも、「おすすめ」を聞きたいのであれば、編集で差し戻してももらって構いませんが、その場合は、私はクローズ票をいれますので、予めご了承ください。

Comment: みなさんコメントや編集ありがとうございます．
ハードウェアスイッチあるいはスイッチ切り替えモード等，キーボードのみでcaps lockをctrlにできることを想定していました．swapでも良いです．

Comment: 自分で設計・製作する方法は考えていますか？ [【自作キーボード】パーツ＆キーキャップ通販サイトまとめてみた【カスタムキーボード】](https://fkeyhack.com/buildkeyboard-shop)

Comment: 65%キーボードが何か明確ではないという意見があるようです。 次のサイトで定義されているもので有っていますか？ https://deskthority.net/wiki/65%25

Comment: 自作キーボードもまとめサイトは非常に有用そうですね．自作は考えていませんでしたが，自作で何ができるのか，よく分かりそうです．
65%キーボードはまさに上記linkの定義で，60%+矢印等，あるいは75%-functionキーだと思います．
完全一致のキーボードがあるかはわかりませんが，部分一致のキーボードの他の存在例もご存知でしたら回答で提示していただければ幸いです．

Answer (score 0):

現在の質問タイトルである、「条件を満たす65%キーボードは存在しますか?」について言えば、存在するようです。

[Majestouch MINILA-R Convertibleのご紹介 | ダイヤテック株式会社](https://www.diatec.co.jp/shop/MINILA-R/)
[【Hothotレビュー】FILCOの“親指Fnキー”小型メカニカルキーボードの使いやすさを検証 ～8月5日より予約開始の「MINILA-R-Convertible」をレビュー - PC Watch](https://pc.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/column/hothot/1269405.html)

- キーボードのdip switchでcaps lockをctrlに変更できる
- 英語配列である
- 65% keyboardについて、指標が記されておらず、調べても明確な定義がなかったのであなたの思う「65%キーボード」にこれが該当するかは分かりませんが、少なくともアローキーはFnキーとの組み合わせて使用可能である
- Bluetoothでの接続に対応しており、wireless接続である
- 記事によると、Cherry MXのスイッチを採用しており、静音赤軸と黒軸のタイプがある
- デザインは主観的なものであるため、あなたにとって「デザインがかっこいい」かは分かりません。

ということで、条件を満たすキーボードは存在するようです。

Comment: これは 60% レイアウト キーボードですね。質問者の意図はおそらく、 物理矢印キーが無く(= 60% キーボード)ても大丈夫なのか不安なので、矢印キー付きのキーボード(= 65% キーボード)にしたい、ということかと。

Answer (score 0):

Ducky One 3 SF

- caps lockをctrlに変更できる
- 有線
- 銀軸可
- hotswap可

https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B09RLVBYL4

Drop ALT

- caps lockをctrlに変更できるか不明
- 有線
- リニア軸がKaihua silver
- hotswap可

https://drop.com/buy/drop-alt-mechanical-keyboard?defaultSelectionIds=966466%2C966471

keychron k6

- caps lockをctrlに変更できない
- 有線/無線
- 赤青茶軸
- hotswap可
- 安い

https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k6-wireless-mechanical-keyboard?variant=31441092149337